# JMeter class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException<

Tags: jmeter

Can some one help me fix this issue in JMeter?
I already use my Regular Expression Extractor after editing javax.face

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[See your server log [enter image description here][1]for more information]]></error-message></error></partial-response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your regular expression extractor fails somewhere somehow, double check that it is returning the expected value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination.

Also using regular expressions might not be the best idea, if you're extracting [Viewstate](https://www.synacktiv.com/ressources/JSF_ViewState_InYourFace.pdf) from the HTML response - it might be a better idea to consider using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) instead